# Mock a method only when arguments satisfy a condition

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm using the `PowerMockito` and `Mockito` libraries. In mocking a method I need to declare a return value only if the method input, which is of the type JsonObject, satisfies some conditions. For example, for all inputs that the value for the key `query` equals to `queryValue`, return the declared value.
I ended in the following code where I can check the input in the `then` method which is good but the problem is I think for JsonObjects where the condition does not satisfy, it will return a null value as I must return a value for the `then` method.

```
final String queryValue = "some values";
PowerMockito.when(instance.myMethod(Mockito.any(JsonObject.class)))
.then(ans -> {
            JsonObject input = ans.getArgument(0);
            if (queryValue.equals(graphQlQuery.getString("query")))
                return resultValue;
            else
                return null;
        });
```

So I was wondering is there any way to specify such a condition on inputs when a method is being called?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write your own Mockito matcher. Have a look at the code of Mockito.any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different *argument matcher* than `any`. [Mockito Documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) has examples that show how to match different arguments.

In your example, you don't need something complicated:

```java
.when(instance.myMethod(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(
    (JsonObject input) -> queryValue.equals(input.getString("query"))
)))
.thenReturn(resultValue)
```

---

> the problem is I think for JsonObjects where the condition does not satisfy, it will return a null value as I must return a value for the then method.

Just to avoid any misunderstanding: If you use the code above, the mock still returns a default value (`null`) for the calls that are not matched by any stubs.

What is different with this code is that you can add *other* stubs with different matchers, that handle different cases (when the argument is not "query"). In your original code, you had to handle all calls in the same place.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Just one question, I observed that at first the `when` method will be called with the value `null` for the `input` variable, so I should use an `if` statement to filter `null` values to avoid `NullPointerException`. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Is `myMethod` being called with `null`? When does that happen? Or is it the input in `(JsonObject input) -> queryValue.equals(input.getString("query"))` that is being `null`? In that case, again, when is it called?